# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 - Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am getting this problem when I try to build my app:

[image]

I got the problem when after trying to update my Cocoa pods.

EDIT:

Is this what you were talking about @nunofmendes?

[image]

EDIT 2:

My pods project looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I cant see your picture but some of your libs may not support arm64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to check your CocoaPods projects. In Build Settings of each project, check the Architectures.

You should have:

> **Architectures**: $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
>   **Valid Architectures**: armv7 armv7s arm64

This occurs when some projects aren't building to ARM64 when you are trying to compile to an 64bit device (like iPhone 5 or greater)

EDIT#1
You can also try setting **Build For Active Architectures** to **YES**

Like in the following image (ignore the valid architectures field in this image):

[image]

Comment: yes. clean project and build it. It should work (if the library supports 64bit)

Comment: Should I be checking specifically for UICKeyChain and MRProgressOverlayView?

Comment: You should check all pod projects, including yours, so that build settings are a match through projects.

Comment: Is this for the Pods project or my app?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, both.

Comment: It seems to have removed those errors, 2 less errors to worry about :) really appreciate the help!

Comment: iPhone 5 is `armv7s` instead of `arm64`.

Answer (score 4):

After successfully updated your cocoapods. You just focus on the build settings. I just modified the below things it's works for me.

To check in your project wheather the pods updated properly or not.
if not you have to install it again.

Change the below metion commands in your Build Settings.
Hope it will helpful for you.!

**Build Settings:**

> Valid Architecture:   arm64 armv7 armv7s
>
> Bitcode Enable:  NO  (if your working iOS9)
>
> Other Linker flag:  -ObjC -lc++ $(inherited)
>
> Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

**Build Active architecture only:**

> Debug - Yes
>
> Release - No

**Search Paths**

> Framework search path - $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)
>
> Library search path - $(inherited)
>
> Header search path - $(inherited)